# printing the html with custom spacing between printer margin and the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am printing the dynamically created html iframe. when i call the  window.frames['fr-print'].print(); method it print the html document but while printing the document i want to have space between margin of the printer and my html content because i want to have the copy right message in bottom of the every page so i have made a div and achieved it by setting the div position as position:fixed; bottom:0; but my content in every page is overlapping with the copy right message. is there any way to give the space between the printer margin and the html content of every page.

I have included margin bottom for @page CSS rule but it affects the margin settings of the printer. and also tried adding whole dynamic control into one div  and added margin bottom for the div but it's only applying the margin in the last page it seems.

Answer (score 0):

WHEN YOU CLICK ON PRINT BUTTON THEN THIS TEXT REMOVE.
$("#COPYRIGHT-ID").TEXT("");